# How can I reverse the triangular array equation $k = (i - 1)(n - \frac{i}{2}) + j - i$ to find the $\{i, j\}$ pair that results in $k$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I am trying to solve the problem below from the [MMDS](http://www.mmds.org) textbook. I can plug the equation into Excel to see that $i=7,\text{ }j=8$ is the solution, but I haven't been able to reverse the equation.

> $\mathbf{Exercise\,\ 6.2.1:}$ If we use a triangular matrix to count pairs, and $n$, the number of items, is $20$, what pair's count is in $a[100]?$

For a bit of context, here's what the book has to say about triangular matrices:

> **The Triangular-Matrix Method**
>
> Even after coding items as integers, we still have the problem that we must count a pair $\{i,j\}$ in only one place. For example, we could order the pair so that $i<j$, and only use the entry $a[i,j]$ in a two-dimensional array $a$. That strategy would make half the array useless. A more space-efficient way is to use a one-dimensional *triangular array.* We store in $a[k]$ the count for the pair $\{i,j\}$, with $1\le i<j\le n$, where $$k=(i-1)\Big(n-\frac{i}{2}\Big)+j-i$$ The result of this layout is that the pairs are stored in lexicographic order, that is first $\{1,2\},\:\{1,3\},\ldots,\{1,n\}$, then $\{2,3\},\:\{2,4\},\ldots,\{2,n\}$, and so on, down to $\{n-2,n-1\},\:\{n-2,n\}$, and finally $\{n-1,n\}$.

Here are the steps I took:

$$
\begin{align}
k &= (i - 1)(n - \frac{i}{2}) + j - i \\ 
k &= ni - \frac{i^2}{2} - n + \frac{i}{2} + j - i \\
100 &= 20i - \frac{i^2}{2} - 20 + \frac{i}{2} + j - i \\
120 &= 19.5i - \frac{i^2}{2} + j
\end{align} 
$$

But that already seems incorrect because plugging in the values of $i=7,\text{ }j=8$ into the last line of the work shown above doesn't check out, but I know that $i=7,\text{ }j=8$ are correct because, as expected:

$$
\begin{align}
(7 - 1)(20 - \frac{7}{2})+8-7 &= \\
6(20 - 3.5) + 1 &= 100 \\
\end{align}
$$

How should I solve this? Am I just bad at algebra?

---

(EDIT)

Okay, I am bad at algebra. The above actually holds, but how do I finish solving for $i$ and $j$? I'm getting an unexpected answer.

$$120=19.5i-\frac{i^2}{2}+j$$

${}$

$$\begin{align}
0&=\left(-\frac{i^2}{2}\right)+19.5i+(j-120) \\
&=i^2-39i+(-2)(j-120)                        \\
&=i^2-39i+(-2j+240)                          \\[0.15ex]
&=i^2-39i+(240-2j)
\end{align}$$

${}$

$$\frac{39\mp\sqrt{1521-4(240-2j)}}{2}=0$$

${}$

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\pm\sqrt{1521-4(240-2j)}}{2}&=-39 \\
1521-4(240-2j)&=1521                    \\
-4(240-2j)&=0                           \\
240-2j&=0                               \\
2j&=240                                 \\
j&=120\:\,???                           \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: $120 = 19.5i - \frac{i^2}{2} + j$ holds for $i=7,j=8$.

Comment: Dang, you are right. Would you know how I finish solving for _i_ and _j_ from there?

Comment: You need to use the inequality $1\le i\lt j\le n$. Solving this for $j=120-19.5i+\frac{i^2}{2}$ and $n=20$ will give you only one integer $i=7$.

Answer (score 1):

You went wrong when you set $$\frac{39\mp\sqrt{1521-4(240-2j)}}{2}=0,$$ because the expression on the left-hand side is equal to $i$ (since you solved the preceeding quadratic equation for $i$), and by definition, $i$ can't be $0$.

---

Here's one way to do it, though I imagine better solutions exist.

Expanding on mathlove's comment, you can solve the equation $$i^2-39i+240-2j=0$$ for either $i$ or $j$ (though I would very strongly recommend solving it for $j$) and plug in integer values of the other variable until you find a pair that satisfies $1\le i\lt j\le n$. Solving the above equation for $j$ to get $$j=\frac{1}{2}i^2-\frac{39}{2}i+120$$ and starting with $i=1$, moving up by steps of $1$, the first (and only) solution you find is $i=7,j=8$.